# Dealing with Paths/Links on Production and Development in JS

Tags: javascript, path, relative-path, web-deployment

I have some websites on development and production separated by folders like: localhost/demo1 localhost/demo2..demo3 and so on.

The problem is my JS. Everytime I deploy them I have to change some paths on JS files, specially the ones that uses AJAX.

Suppose the code below is the URL parameter in jquery ajax:

```
//on dev:
url: '/demo1/some-action.php'

//on prod:
url: '/some-action.php'
```

How do you handle this on JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare a function that returns the folder path depending on the location of the calling page
something like

```
function sitePath(){
    if(this.result!=undefined){
        // we have already tested so return the stored value
        return this.result
    }
    var folders=window.location.pathname.split('/');
    if(folders.length && folders[0].indexOf('demo')==0){
        // we are inside a demo folder so return and store the demo folder name
        return this.result='/' + folders[0];
    }else{
        // we are in the production environment so store an empty string
        return this.result = '';
    }
}
```

Then in your code you would use:

```
url: sitePath()+'/some-action.php'
```

Comment: kevmc, sorry for the late, I checked this and forgot to give you the correct answer.

Comment: I think it should be `folders[1]`. For me, `folders = ["","demo",...]`.